# Maven, lost local dependency | Could not resolve dependencies for project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Hi guys I have a Maven project working well since 9 months.

But today I get a error in Maven build

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project bon: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mydev:bon:war:1.0.20.1: Failure to find com.mydev:utils:jar:1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven2 has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

The project is a Dynamic Web Project with maven

In `pom` I have a dependency to  local jar

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mydev</groupId>
        <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

The project `com.mydev.utils` has installed in my PC in `.m2` folder, I check the folder `D:\.m2\repository\com\mydev\utils\1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT\` and everything seems in order

```
_rzi_0.118
_rzi_0.227
_maven.repositories
utils-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
utils-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar.lastUpdate
utils-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom
utils-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom.lastUpdate
m2e.lastUpdate.properties
maven-metadata-local.xml
resolver-status.properties
```

I do not think the problem is the pom, I have not changed anything

I tried to build another project with the same unit, and get the same error.

I install software yesterday ([DB2 Express-C database server](https://www-01.ibm.com/marketing/iwm/iwm/web/pick.do?source=swg-db2expressc&S_PKG=dlwin64&S_TACT=100KG26W&lang=en_US)), not if maven may have lost some settings for it. wheninstall the software, do not restart
Today try to generate the war, but I get the error, I reboot the PC, but I have the same error

Edit:

[image: Eclipse congif, maven]

Comment: What software you have installed yesterday ?

Comment: @SandeepBhardwaj DB2 Express-C database server

Comment: 1) If you trying to run using eclipse then verify maven settings so that it points to correct maven repository.  2) if you are running using cmd then check your setting.xml of maven. It seems it's not pointing to correct local maven repository.

Comment: @SandeepBhardwaj Oh! I eclipse see a warning `User settings file doesn't exist` I have settings ref to `D:\.m2\settings.xml` but in folder is nothing

Comment: I would have expected to see your maven repository under eg. c:\users\jasilva\.m2. Does that directory exist? And when you say "local jar" do you have the project and how did you install it to maven?

Comment: Yes, exist a folder like `C:\Users\jasilva\.m2\repository` but in `C:\Users\jasilva\.m2\repository\com\mydev\utils\1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT` but no has a jar. Maven config change  to this path??

Comment: @jasilva Finally you got it. We face this issue whenever we create new workspace in eclipse.

Comment: @SandeepBhardwaj Ok, but I did not create a new workspace, for a long time

Comment: Have you try to remove utils-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar.lastUpdate
 and utils-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom.lastUpdate? Or even keep only the pom and the jar files.

Comment: @SandeepBhardwaj Ok, i remove the 2 files, but error persist

Comment: @SandeepBhardwaj I copy jar and pom files from `D:\.m2` to `C:User..\.m2` folder, and get a error, but attempt again and build success, what happend??

Comment: @jasilva Not sure what happens. One more thing you do not need to do copy and paste thing , you can just easily modify your maven 'setting.xml' for maven repo and in eclipse point it to correct file. In above scree shot user setting path should be you maven installation dir like '<your dir>\apache-maven-xxx\conf\'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more thing you do not need to do copy and paste thing , you can just easily modify your maven `setting.xml` for maven repo and in eclipse point it to correct file. In above scree shot user setting path should be you maven installation dir like `<your dir>\apache-maven-xxx\conf\settings.xml`

**settings.xml**

```
<localRepository>D:\.m2</localRepository>
```